# How to merge tag to master branch during release by maven-release-plugin?

Tags: git, maven, devops, git-flow, maven-release-plugin

I have configured maven-release-plugin in the following way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
        <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Let's use in example that project has version: 1.3.10-SNAPSHOT

I use following command for release (in develop branch; vcs is git):

```
mvn -B initialize release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

So, during the release procedure tag v1.3.10 is created.
After the release, version in pom is 1.3.11-SNAPSHOT.

I want to automatic merge of tag v1.3.10 to branch master. How to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe I miss a thing but are you doing your release from master ? Ah sorry missed...you wrote from developer branch...and the answer is simply: No. BTW: You should merge the develop branch back to master...

Comment: BTW: Why do you call `initialize` before `release:clean` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, initialize before release:clean is superfluous.

"You should merge the develop branch back to master..."
@khmarbaise I am not sure I undestood, could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

As commented, no, unless you extend somehow the `mvn release` plugin itself.

A better practice would be to merge `dev` to `master` first, then apply the `mvn release` plugin.

Comment: When I merge dev to master first (before maven release) I will have version 1.3.10-SNAPSHOT in master branch, but I want to have: 1.3.10

Comment: @bmilczarek you will, once you do the mvn release call from the master branch.